# Is there an equivalent for string.find() in window objects?

Tags: javascript, replace, window

So I know window.find(), an unstandard js object that finds a string on the page, it returns `true` if found and `false` if not.
Now is there somthing similar to string.replace(), but is a window object (ex : window.replace()) that would replace all concurrent elements to soemthing else (eg replace all of the "Hi" to "Hello")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, but it's easier to write than you might suspect. You just walk the DOM looking for Text nodes and use `replace` on their `nodeValue`:

```
function replaceAll(element, regex, replacement) {
    for (var child = element.firstChild;
         child;
         child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) { // Text
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(regex, replacement);
        } else if (child.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            replaceAll(child, regex, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

There I used a regular expression (which needs to have the `g` flag) to get the "global" behavior when doing the replace, and for flexibility.

Live Example:

```js
function replaceAll(element, regex, replacement) {
    for (var child = element.firstChild;
         child;
         child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) { // Text
            child.nodeValue = child.nodeValue.replace(regex, replacement);
        } else if (child.nodeType === 1) { // Element
            replaceAll(child, regex, replacement);
        }
    }
}

setTimeout(function() {
    replaceAll(document.body, /one/g, "two");
}, 800);
```

```html
<div>
  Here's one.
  <p>And here's one.</p>
  <p>And here's <strong>one</strong>
</div>
```

If you want to use a simple string instead of a regular expression, just use a regular expression escape function (such as the ones in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) and build your regex like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(yourEscapeFunction(simpleString), "g");
```

---

The case this doesn't handle is where the target string crosses text nodes, like this:

```html
<span>ex<span>ample</span></span>
```

Using the function above looking for `"example"`, you wouldn't find it. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to handle that case if desired... :-)

Comment: Thnx. I didn't see this until now.